# $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ continuous, $l\in\Bbb R$. Show $S=\{x \in\Bbb R^n:f(x) \le l\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

For a function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be continuous and $l\in\Bbb R$. I have to prove that the set $S=\{x \in\Bbb R^n:f(x) \le l\}$ is closed and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How have you been defined 'closed set'?

Answer (score 3):

$S$ is the preimage of $(-\infty, l]$, a closed set, and $f$ is continuous.

*Remark*: This proof is based on the fact of the preimage of a closed set is a closed set, if the function is continuous:

Indeed, let $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ be a continuous function. Let $F\subset\Bbb R^m$ a closed set, and $U=\Bbb R^m-F$, which is open. Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Since $x$ is continuous,
$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0:\|\xi-x\|<\delta\to\|f(\xi)-f(x)\|<\epsilon$$

Now, take an open ball $B_1=B(f(x),\epsilon)$. As stated, the ball $B_0=B(x,\delta)$ is in the preimage of $B_1$ and hence in the preimage of $U$. This shows that the preimage of $U$ is open, for we have taken a point $x$ and have found an open neighbourhood contained in this preimage.

But then, $\Bbb R^n-f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\Bbb R^m-U)=f^{-1}(F)$ is a closed set, q.e.d.

I hope now you find that this is a proof.

Comment: This is a proof.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I might have been confused because I have never heard of 'preimage'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, suppose $(x_n) \subset S$ converges to $x$. As $f$ is continuous, $(f(x_n))$ also converges to $f(x)$. As each $f(x_n) \leq \ell$ it must be that $f(x) \leq \ell$ and hence $x \in S$.

Now depending on what your course demands of you, there are some details to fill in here.

Comment: Maybe something to do with taking the limits? Is that possible?