# Show that $A=\{x\in X\mid a\leq f(x)\leq b\:;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is closed if $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a set. Suppose that $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and let $A=\{x\in X\mid a\leq f(x)\leq b\:;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Is $A$ closed, open, clopen or none?

So I started by saying that $f(A)=\{p=f(x)\mid a\leq p\leq b\;\text{for some}\;x\in X\}$ but I can't figure out if the set is closed.

Comment: $A$ is the preimage of a closed set, so ...

Comment: How do I show that $f(A)$ is closed?

Comment: If $X=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=x$ then $A=[a,b]$. Is it open?

Comment: There is a very similar answered question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020426/f-bbb-rn-to-bbb-r-continuous-l-in-bbb-r-show-s-x-in-bbb-rnfx-l/1020428#1020428

Comment: The question concerns set $A$ and not set $f(A)$.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $f(A)$ is closed

Comment: But isn't $f^{-1}(A)=A$ in this case? If so, if I can show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed then $A$ is closed by the continuity of $f$

Comment: @AdelSaleh In general, $f^{-1}(A)$ clsed does not imply $A$ closed, even for continouos $f$. On the contrary, $A$ closed implie $f^{-1}(A)$ closed for continouos $f$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant $f^{-1}(f(A))$. Since in this case $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ then we can try to show that $f(A)$ is closed and hence $A$ is closed

Comment: $f(A)$ is not necessarily closed. To see this, let $X=\mathbb R$, $a=-\pi/2$ $b=\pi/2$, and $f=\arctan$. Then, $A=\mathbb R$ and $f(A)=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, which is _not_ closed in $\mathbb R$.

However, $A$ _is_ closed in $X$ for any topological space $X$. This is because $A=f^{-1}([a,b])$ by definition, and $[a,b]$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R$. Now use the fact that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is always closed.

Comment: Again to clear things out, in this specific case it happened to be that $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$. So if I can show that $f(A)$ is closed, then $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ closed. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: @AdelSaleh _If_ you can show that $f(A)$ is closed, _then_ $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is closed as well. However, the problem is that $f(A)$ cannot be guaranteed to be closed in general. It _may_ be, but not necessarily so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is closed.

The simplest way to see it is the following: Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\{x:a\le f(x)\le b\}$, with $x_n\to x_0$. Then, 
$$
a\le f(x_n)\le b, \quad\text{for all $n$},
$$
and as $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$, which implies that
$$
a\le f(x_0)\le b.
$$
Thus $x_0\in\{x:a\le f(x)\le b\}$, and hence $\{x:a\le f(x)\le b\}$ is closed.

Comment: Could you please just explain: $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$, which implies that $a≤f(x_0)≤b$.

Answer (score 1):

By (some variant of) definition, a map $f\colon X\to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous iff $f^{-1}(S)$ is a closed subset of $X$ whenever $S$ is a closed subset of $Y$. The interval $[a,b]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed. You have that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Then it follows.

To show that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, take any $x \in \overline{A}$ then there exists $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ a sequence with elements in $A$ such that $\lim a_n = x$. As $f$ is continuous you have that $\lim f(a_n) = f(x)$ and

$$a\leq f(a_n) \leq b \Rightarrow a \leq \lim f(a_n) \leq b \Rightarrow a \leq f(x) \leq b $$

Then $x \in A$ so $\overline{A} = A$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff for any open set $B\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is also open. This is also the definition of continuity.

So notice that $[a,b]$ is closed, so $A=X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus [a,b])$ is closed.